# caracteres extraños al actualizar mi versión de php

Tags: caracteres

Os quería preguntar en relación a que tengo algunas páginas alojadas en un hosting de pago. El caso es que ahora mismo las tengo funcionando con la version 5.5 de php, donde en lo que se refiere a los textos, se ven perfectamente . Sin embargo si yo desde mi panel de control cambio a la version de php a la 7.2 se ven caracteres extraños sobre todo en los acentos en los textos (adjunto captura).El caso que he cambiado la línea dentro de head y he cambiado a UTF-8 y tampoco logro solventar el problema.

En cualquier caso si cambio la línea tengo muchos ficheros como 500 y cambiarlos uno a uno es mucho trabajo yo no se si desde el archivo .htacces se puede aplicar alguna directiva para que funcione toda la web con la última versión de php.
Os adjunto una captura de la visualización del texto[image: Captura de un párrafo de texto]

El código interno de la página, he quitado el contenido:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="Keywords" content="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<LINK Rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css" Type="text/css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<header>    
<?php include("cabecera.php"); ?><aside><?php include("buscadorinterno.php"); ?></aside>
   <header>
<nav>
   <?php include("navegacion.php"); ?>
 </nav> <section> 
 <h1>título</h1>
 <p class="center"><strong>Edición</strong>: 5 Agosto, 2020</p>
    
 <p class="center">
 texto</p>
        
            <p align="center" class="center"><a href="javascript:window.history.back()" class="ver">&lt;&lt; 
   Volver</a> </p>
 <div class="banner_mobile"></div>
 <div class="banner_pc"> 
 </div>
 <div class="banner_mobile"> 
   <?php include("bannermovile.php"); ?>
 </div>
 <div class="banner_pc"> 
   <?php include("bannerblog.php"); ?>
 </div>
 </section> <aside> 
</aside><footer> 
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
   </footer>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muestra el contexto desde el cual obtienes ese contenido para mostrarlo en pantalla. Tendrías que configurar UTF-8 en diferentes niveles según ese contexto: en PHP, en la conexión a la base de datos si los datos vienen de allí, en el HTML, etc.

Comment: Las páginas tienen extensión php pero no tienen conexión a ninguna base de datos. He configurado UTF-8 y no funciona siguen sin poder verse correctamente. El código fuente de la página:

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%c3%a1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base)

Comment: Bien parece que encontré la solución al problema, pero me va a dar mucho trabajo. Si cojo el código lo copio, abro el bloc de notas y lo pego, posteriormente le dio a guardar UTF-8 , bingo la página se ve correctamente.